# CentOS 5 ssl update failure

Tags: ssl, openssl, centos5

On Centos 5 I'm trying to download via HTTPS but I'm getting cert errors:

```
$ curl https://nixos.org/nix/install
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
...
```

There's various answers to this question around ([for example](https://gist.github.com/taylor/2968566)), which say to download https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem onto `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

On another machine, I've downloaded https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and copied it to the Centos5 machine at `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

However, I still get the same error

```
$ curl https://nixos.org/nix/install
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Is there an extra step I'm missing?

Comment: CentOS 5 is out of support for nearly a year now. Time to switch to something supported.

Comment: I don't even think the ancient OpenSSL in CentOS 5 can validate some modern certificates. That thing should have been decommissioned years ago.

Comment: nevertheless there are businesses that use it in the real world (not that ficticious one where magically everything is always up to date) that might need to solve this problem.